# Does the Bilderberg Group have influence on world events?

Tags: economics, politics

Is there any evidence to support the claim the [Bilderberg Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilderberg_Group) have control of the world and its money supply?

Is there evidence to suggest they are planning on exterminating the majority of the earths population in order to control the world's resources?

Examples of these claims can be seen by searching "bilderberg exterminating" in Google.

e.g.

[however, their big plan is to exterminate 90% of the Earth's human
populace](http://etherzone.com/2006/stang112406.shtml)

Comment: I dont know what *evidence* can prove this, there are media reports which are a lot of hearsay and the internet sites are awash with those who believe in secret cabals and the Illuminati. There are at least 3 books published by journalists who have sensationalized details intended to sell their books. There is no published manifesto which states they want to exterminate 80% of the world's population.

Comment: Given that people are one of the major resources a group seeking to control power and influence would desire, destroying 90% of the popuation seems counter-productive. Controlling the money supply is pointless if there is nothing of value being produced to create a demand for that money.

Comment: I ask myself how an organization, which meets once per year, should organize something of real evidence. But since I can't cite a study - you know ...

Comment: If the goal is to kill most people so they can own the world's resources, their economics is a little naive and self-contradictory. If there were far fewer people, there wouldn't be anyone to use or pay for the resources, so they wouldn't be worth much. They are valuable now because so many people want them.

Answer (score 13):

From what I have seen there is no credible source for the claim of an official release coming from Bilderberg detailing an agenda of depopulation. It is claimed in many places on the internet but none of these provide reliable evidence that this is the case.

There are some interesting snippets from the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilderberg_Group) worth noting in relation to your question:

> According to Thompson, Bilderberg itself is not an executive agency.
>   However, when Bilderberg participants reach a form of consensus about
>   what is to be done, they have at their disposal powerful transnational
>   and national instruments for bringing about what it is they want to
>   come to pass.

So this points to the fact that they do have significant power at their disposal, so yes they do have some influence on world events.

> In 2001, Denis Healey, a Bilderberg group founder and, for 30 years, a
>   steering committee member, said: "To say we were striving for a
>   one-world government is exaggerated, but not wholly unfair. Those of
>   us in Bilderberg felt we couldn't go on forever fighting one another
>   for nothing and killing people and rendering millions homeless. So we
>   felt that a single community throughout the world would be a good
>   thing."

This is confirmation from someone in the group that they were looking to influence world politics.

I don't think any further proof is necessary. It is obvious that they have significant power based upon who is invited and their positions and assets. It is also obvious based on the quote by Denis Healey that as part of their work they would be influencing world events in some way.

There is no evidence to suggest that they have agenda which requires exterminating large parts of the population.

Answer (score 2):

I will just add a quick note that I don't want to be lost in comments - WikiLeaks published (before they went famous) a Bilderberg reports from 50s, 60s and 1980.

It **is** a rather interesting read, but it also shows that they don't really control the world, more discussing the current politics. A lot of the context is lost with time, though.

[All the reports are categorized here.](http://wikileaks.org/wiki/Category%3aSeries/Bilderberg_reports)

Comment: And what does the report say?